# Oracle / PLSQL: TRANSLATE Function - Why does this return NULL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to Oracle / PLSQL and I was testing some code lines using TRANSLATE function.

Scenario 1:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TRANSLATE('27383', '0123456789', ' '));
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LENGTH(TRANSLATE('27383', '0123456789', ' ')));
```

I get output as:

```
NULL
NULL
```

Scenario 2:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TRANSLATE('2021 01 01', '0123456789', ' '));
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(LENGTH(TRANSLATE('2021 01 01', '0123456789', ' ')));
```

I get output as:

```
5 space characters
5
```

I thought, as the to_string is one character `' '` (space), the first occurrence is getting replaced and other values are getting removed from the original string.

Like, in `'2021 01 01'`, `'0'` is replaced with `' '` and the rest of the numerical characters are removed making it a string with 5 space characters (2 spaces it originally had plus 3 spaces from the replacement).

By this logic, in the first scenario, `'2'` should be replaced with `' '` removing other numbers. Remaining should be a string with one space character, but it's not what is happening.

Can someone explain to me what happens here?

Comment: Your thinking error: `By this logic, in the first scenario, '2' should be replaced with ' '` this should be  *zero* (first character of the second parameter) not *two* -> `... '0' should be replaced with ' ' ` and the first string has no zeroes so you get `NULL`.

Comment: Try `TRANSLATE('27383', '0123456789', 'ABCDEFGHIJ')` and then `TRANSLATE('27383', '0123456789', 'ABCD')` to get a better idea of what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you @MarmiteBomber !
I tried a few more examples. Now I understand that I have to consider the remaining positions in the replacement string as NULLs.

Comment: And thank you @kfinity :) I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a one-to-one pairing of before/after values, and that we need a one-to-one pair for *everything*.

Thus considering: '0123456789', ' '

The first string has 10 "positions", so the second string needs 10 positions, namely:

space,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,

So

- 0 goes to space
- 1 goes to null
- 2 goes to null

and so forth.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now understand how it works! ^_^